# Swift CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NSManagedObject'

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

I'm using core data to save a category in vc1 and want to add list properties to a list in vc2. My data model is one category to many list properties.

I'm adding the category like this in vc1:

```
func createNewCategory() {
    var category: NSManagedObject! = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: self.context) as NSManagedObject
    category.setValue(self.categoryTextField.text, forKey: "name")

    var error: NSError? = nil
    self.context.save(&error)
}
```

Setting up the data in vc2:

```
func setupCoreData() {
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication()).delegate as AppDelegate
    self.context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    var request: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Category")
    if (self.context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)) {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        self.listData = self.context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
        self.managedObject = self.listData.objectAtIndex(0) as NSManagedObject
    }
}
```

It crashes on the last row: `self.managedObject = ...` saying:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NSManagedObject'
```

The managed object is in the array if I put a break point and print the array. What's wrong?

Comment: You are executing the fetch request twice. Why?

Comment: I was checking if it existed, but it seemed to work without it...

Comment: The test just checks if the fetch returns an array, even an empty one.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I'm a novice as you can tell :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dedicated initializer is

```
class func insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_ entityName: String!,
   inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) -> AnyObject!
```

Clearly, you are not inserting a new object, so you really want an optional value. Maybe you declared your class variable `managedObject` as `NSManagedObject!`? Try setting it to `NSManagedObject?` and also change the operator to `as?`.

Comment: Setting ut up like this:
var managedObject: NSManagedObject? = NSManagedObject?()
self.managedObject = self.listData.objectAtIndex(0) as? NSManagedObject
seemed to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An entity in CoreData is equivalent to a class. Did you add the entity to your managed object model, and subclass the entity? (Check out the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) for a fuller background.)