# Segue error - failed to call designated initializer on nsmanagedobject class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, core-data

In tableview controller #1, I initialize an array of NSManagedObjects (entity named "Date") in viewDidLoad. `var datesArray = [Date]()`. I use this array to populate the table data.

When a user selects a cell, I want to pass that selected `Date` object via the index path to view controller #2, a details view. This is what I have in `prepareForSegue` for tableview controller #1:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDateDetails" {
        let dateDetailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DateDetailsVC
        dateDetailsVC.date = datesArray[selectedIndexPath!.row] as Date
    }
}
```

In view controller #2 I have a simple `var date = Date()` property.

When I select a row in the table view, it crashes on `dateDetailsVC.date = datesArray[selectedIndexPath!.row] as Date` with the error:

> CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'DateAid.Date'

Can anyone either guide me to a solution, or explain the reasoning behind why it's happening in semi-layman's terms? I'd like to avoid having to perform a fetch request in view controller #2 unless that's not possible. For context, my Core Data skills are 1.5/5 at the moment.

Comment: How do you populate your 'datesArray' ?

Comment: Through a fetch request on the propogated managed object context. Since I have all the dates in the view controller #1 'datesArray' I was hoping not to have to fetch them again in view controller #2.

Comment: ok, and how did you declare date in  dateDetailsVC? i have one thought about it..

Comment: var date = Date() as a variable property in dateDetailsVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25505878/2382237

Maybe you should declare date like:

```
var date: Date?
```

and some refactor :

```
 dateDetailsVC.date = datesArray[selectedIndexPath!.row] as? Date
```